# How can i use a matrix in tkinter

Tags: python, list, matrix, tkinter

I need use a matrix in python using tkinter, this my code:

```
from tkinter import *
V=Tk()
a=IntVar()
b=IntVar()
c=IntVar()

a1=IntVar()
b1=IntVar()
c1=IntVar()

a2=IntVar()
b2=IntVar()
c2=IntVar()

a.set(5)
b.set(8)
c.set(10)


a1.set(5)
b1.set(8)
c1.set(10)

matriz=[
    [a,b,c],
    [a1,b1,c1],
    [a2,b2,c2],
    ]

for x in range(3):
    matriz[2][x].set (matriz[0][x]-matriz[1][x])
```

How i can set the variables a2,b2,b3 using a matrix and add the variables to a labels in the frame

Comment: What problem are you having? The solution is no more complicated than a simple loop.

Comment: The problem is i cant set the value of a Intvar using a matrix

Comment: Sorry, my code is bad and i use this:                                                                                                          for x in range(3):
    matriz[2][x].set (matriz[0][x].get()-matriz[1][x].get())

l=Label(textvariable=a2)
l.pack()

Comment: What does this have to do with tkinter?  There isn't a GUI anywhere.  "Add the variable to label in the frame?"  You don't have a frame.